# How to sharpen or blur text in php library using ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Is it possible to do what is asked in the title? I've tried with imagedraw with settextaliased, but that didn't work.
I just have image and trying to add sharpened or blurred text to it.

Comment: `Is it possible to do something.` Do what?  This is a very poor question. There is not enough information to help us know what you want and what you have tried. Please add more information and the code you have tried and the image you start with and the result you are getting. If you cannot post images directly here, then post to some free hosting service and put the links here to the images.

Comment: Add blur text to image with php imagick